# Meaning of “it don't matter”?

Tags: conjugations

When I watched a movie in English, I heard a man say “it don't matter”.

What does *it **don't** matter* mean?

Does it sound similar to *it **doesn't** matter?*

Comment: Yes, what you are thinking is right: *"it don't matter"* means the same thing as *"it doesn't matter"*. You'll often find that many native English speakers might use phrases similar to *"it don't matter"* in informal speech, and it is currently considered to be non-standard English.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

“It don’t matter” and “it doesn’t matter” are semantically equivalent.

“It don’t matter” goes against prescriptive grammar, but it is an extremely common usage in casual registers and various dialects.

You might choose this phrase to intentionally indicate a casual view of something, either sincerely or sarcastically. It probably gets a lot of use because people saying it are trying to communicate that something doesn’t matter, and that’s best done in a way that demonstrates lack of interest (in rules).

Answer (score 1):

It's just vernacular. Best not to overthink it. Just imagine he's a fellow English learner.

Other examples include "ain't," "let me axe you a question," and "bitnezz (business)."

Comment: The wording is probably not because he's a "learner"; the wording is probably because he's grown up in an environment where grammar was not stressed. I think there's a difference. Moreover, two of your three other examples are pronunciation variants, not grammatical variants. That all said, I do agree that "ain't" is similar in use: grammatically incorrect, yet still spoken in some subcultures.

Comment: @J.R. *Ain't* is non-standard, but this isn't a matter of grammar.  In fact, it has its own grammatical rules and is usually used grammatically in non-standard Englishes.  The following is grammatical but non-standard: *!She ain't so bright.*  And the following is ungrammatical: *\*I try to ain't sleep this early.*  (Here, the `!` marks an utterance as non-standard, while the `*` marks ungrammaticality.)

Comment: Goodness, some of the people in this website are so uptight. The part about him being a learner was obviously a joke.

Answer (score 0):

"It don't matter" is not English but a part of an English dialect or creole. I would imagine that this comes from an American dialect of some sort, as it was regarded as someone speaking "English". Or, perhaps - as suggested the person is learning English which internationally tends to be taught through the "American" dialect of English and not "British" English.

I would avoid the use of "It don't matter" and stick to "It doesn't matter" - **using "It don't matter" does matter**, to many it makes you appear ignorant of how to speak correctly.

**UPDATE**

People seem to have a misunderstanding about dialects and Languages. A dialect IS NOT a language. It makes USE of a language which in itself does NOT make them comparable nor equal. "It don't matter" is a phrase which contains English Language words. But is not an  English Language phrase. It is however, accepted as a dialectal phrase; but that does NOT make it English.

Comment: Maybe this is a British/American difference, but I totally disagree. "It don't matter" is certainly English, although I agree it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: The idea that English does not naturally support or allow double negatives is utter nonsense. The only sense in which a double (or multiple) negative that remains definitively negative is "not grammatically correct" is in the most formal registers, which tend to use a prescriptive grammar that has never been the actual grammar of the English language (though it does make learning Latin and classical Greek easier, which was the point).

Comment: What do double negatives have to do with it?

Comment: If it's part of an English dialect, then it *is* English.  At any rate, it would be more accurate to call this non-standard than ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat there is a difference between "English" and a dialect of "English". These people are learning "English" not "dialects" such as American. IT is really important to differentiate this very early on so that learners know what they are learning!

Comment: @StanRogers English has never had a formal descriptive grammar which is why grammar is no longer taught in school.

Comment: @DaveGordon - Might I suggest that you take a look at Huddleston and Pullam?

Comment: @StanRogers you can suggest what you like. However, I would suggest that you give a reason as to what you wish me to refer to within "Huddleston and Pullum"

Comment: All utterances belong to one dialect or another.  Your answer and comments are no exception.  The phrase in question here is properly labeled **non-standard English**, which is a very different thing from "not an English Language phrase."  The concept you're looking for is that of **standard English**.

Comment: @snailboat thank you for assuming what concept you think I should look for. The notion that all utterances belong to a dialect is ridiculous. You are suggesting that it is impossible to speak any language, only dialects? Utter madness.

Comment: It's just basic linguistics.  For an introduction, I suggest David Crystal's *Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language*.  Once you're familiar with the concept of a dialect you can come back and revise this answer.

Comment: @snailboat NO NO NO!! All dialects belong to a Language - but not all utterances in a Language belong to a dialect! Sheeze how can you not understand something as basic as this? Which dialect does pure un-bastardised English belong to?? None!

Scouse uses English, American uses English - English does not use Scouse nor American. It's like saying all rooms are houses - They are not - houses have rooms, but rooms do not have houses.

Comment: As for David Crystal's Encyclopedia - I full heartedly agree that it is a great book - referred to many a time whilst doing my MA in Linguistics at the University of St Andrews.

Comment: There is, to put it bluntly, no such thing as a "language"; there are merely bundles of dialects, and that is probably more true of English than most "languages". And "Huddleston and Pullum" is *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, which is not the only descriptive grammar of English, but the most scholarly and comprehensive (you asserted that there was *no* descriptive grammar).

Comment: OK ok ok - I will give up. Because someone wrote a book saying this is the descriptive language for English you believe it. That's up to you. 

As for the notion that Language is a collection of dialects  you have found the Linguistic Chicken and Egg problem.